# Yii2 CSRF validation on multiple servers

Tags: php, yii, yii2, load-balancing, csrf

I have application which is deployed on three servers. Using load balancer requests are multiplexed to servers. Issue is that one server generate CSRF token, which is validated on another server, and validation fails.

Should CSRF be kept in DB, as session is, to be same on each server?

Does anyone have solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Idea is to store it in some common place for your servers.

In our case, all of our servers are utilizing one memcache server for session storage, and we didn't face any problem regarding CSRF token.

Also, in case you are using PageCache, you can have problem with CSRF token if it's being cached as well. To avoid caching the CSRF token, you can use `renderDynamic` function in your layout, like following:

```
<?= $this->renderDynamic(' return \yii\helpers\Html::csrfMetaTags(); '); ?>
```